# Prove that $x_n=\frac{a_1}{e^1}+\frac{a_2}{e^2}+...+\frac{a_n}{e^n}$ is a Cauchy sequence

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, cauchy-sequences

The problem I am trying to take is:

> Prove that $x_n=\frac{a_1}{e^1}+\frac{a_2}{e^2}+...+\frac{a_n}{e^n}$ is a Cauchy sequence s.t. $|a_n|\leq1000$

I begin this like other Cauchy sequences proofs, let $n,m$ be some integers and I want to find a minimum for a particular $n_0$ s.t. $\forall m,n\geq n_0 \implies |x_n-x_m|<\epsilon$ where $\epsilon>0$. Here is my attempt: (assuming $n<m$ although this should not affect the basis of the proof):

\begin{align}
|x_n-x_m|\\
=\Biggl|\frac{a_1}{e^1}+\frac{a_2}{e^2}+...+\frac{a_n}{e^n}-\Biggl(\frac{a_1}{e^1}+...+\frac{a_n}{e^n}+...+\frac{a_m}{e^m}\Biggl)\Biggl|\\
=\Biggl|\frac{a_{n+1}}{e^{n+1}}+...+\frac{a_m}{e^m}\Biggl|\\
\leq\Biggl|\frac{1000}{e^{n+1}}+...+\frac{1000}{e^m}\Biggl|<\epsilon
\end{align}

At this point I get a little stuck on how to get a nice lower bound of $n_0$. Does anyone have any hints on how to proceed?

Comment: The indices (and the exponent too, of course) should be $m+1$ to $n$. And you probably want to assume $n\gt m$, not the other way around.

Comment: I'm a little confused, are you pointing out a potential way of solving or a mistake in the problem?

Comment: I thought there was a mistake, but on second thought, your notation works too. It’s just not very conventional, I suppose. Although, doesn’t the desired result follows from the fact that the geometric series with common ratio between $-1$ and $1$ is convergent?

Comment: Hint: $\frac{1000}{e^k} < \frac{1000}{2^k}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have
$$
|x_n - x_m| \leq \sum_{k=n+1}^m \frac{1000}{e^k} = \frac{1000}{e^n} \sum_{k=1}^{m-n} \frac{1}{e^k}
$$
but
$$
\sum_{k=1}^{m - n} \frac{1}{e^k} < \sum_{k=1}^{m-n} \frac{1}{2^k} < 1
$$
so
$$
|x_n - x_m| \leq \frac{1000}{e^n}
$$
so the difference can be arbitrarily small.